# D3js: How to load CSV data and convert it into nvd3.js object?

Tags: jquery, csv, d3.js, key-value, nvd3.js

I have a comma separated file:

```
 dV,  dA, Model, Cell
-1.5, -3.2,  B, xA
-1.1, -2.3,  B, xB
 1.2, -0.8,  B, xC
 6.5,  2.7,  C, xA
 7.4,  4.5,  C, xB
 6.1,  3.3,  C, xC
 24.6, 12.3, D, xA
 25.2, 11.8, D, xB
 29.9, 18.3, D, xC
...
```

And want to convert if into nvd3.js object, where data is grouped by "Cell" column value:

```
{
 key: value from "Cell" column,
 values: {x: .., y: ..., shape: value from "Model" column},
 ...
}
```

To do so I use the following code:

```
function loadData(filename) {

var data = [],
    shapes = {xA: 'circle', xB: 'square;' xC: 'cross']

d3.csv(filename, function(d) {
    if ((data['key' === undefined) || (data.key[d.Cell] === undefined)) {
        data.push{
            key: d.Cell,
            values: []
        }
    }
    data.key[d.Cell].values.push({
        x: +d.dV,
        y: +d.dA,
        size: 3,
        shape: function(d) { return shapes[d.Model] || 'circle'; }
    })
);

return data;

}
```

The code isn't work. What is wrong in the following code, and how to convert CSV data into nvd3.js object?

Answer (score 1):

A few issues with your code:

- Javascript Syntax

The sample posted has Javascript syntax errors (typo's in definition of `shapes`, checking value of `data.key`, `data.push`) - did you try and debug the javascript before posting?

- CSV file has whitespace

D3.js's, CSV parser does not strip white-space, this is especially relevant in the way that you use d.Cell to extract the Cell attribute. D3.js parses it as ' Cell' and not 'Cell'.

- CSV callback function returns an array of parsed rows, not a single row

You need to wrap your row processing code in a `d.forEach(function(rowData) { /* your row processing here */ })`

- Returning of `data` doesn't reflect callback nature of CSV

Your `return data;` is outside of the CSV callback function. So in all probably will be called before the CSV function has done its job.

You need to change your `loadData` function to be an asynchronous pattern. i.e.: let the caller supply a callback function which is called with the processed `data` output, within the CSV function.

- Dataseries not setup properly

I believe that you're looking for your data to be returned in the form:

```
[ { key: 'xA', values: .... }, { key: 'xB', values: .... } .... ]
```

Ie: an array of objects, with each object having a different `key` corresponding to your `Cell` attribute.

However, your `data.key[...]` check is trying to check the `key` attribute on the `data` array itself! It is not evaluating whether there is an object within `data` that has a `key` attribute.

Not necessarily an issue, depending on your NVD3.js setup:

- Is `shapes` key correct?

Your `shapes` lookup is keyed with values `xA`, `xB`, `xC`. From your supplied data, these correspond to values in `Cell`, however you are checking against `d.Model`

- Does `shapes` attribute need to be a function?

Given all the other attributes are straight copies of the CSV parsed data, the `function(d)` approach for shapes is probably creating unnecessary complication.

Just set it directly? `shape: shapes[d.Model] || 'circle'`

Putting all of the above together, I put the sample of code together below that illustrates:

```
        loadData('data.csv', function(data) { console.log(data); });

        function getOrCreateEntry(data, key) {
            data.forEach(function(d) {
                if (d.key === key)
                    return d;
            });

            var newEntry = { key: key, values: [] };

            data.push(newEntry);

            return newEntry;
        }

        function loadData(filename, cb) {

            var data = [],
                shapes = {A: 'circle', B: 'square', C: 'cross'}

            d3.csv(filename,function(csvData) {
                csvData.forEach(function(d) {

                    cellEntry = getOrCreateEntry(data, d.Cell);

                    cellEntry.values.push({
                        x: +d.dV,
                        y: +d.dA,
                        size: 3,
                        shape: shapes[d.Model] || 'circle'
                    })
                });

                cb(data);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've solved my problem in a little bit different manner. Instead of a new procedure which checks does key exist, I add an additional array with key names. But your decision is also very nice.